# Smali best place to inject code

Tags: android, dalvik, smali

I am making a python script to add a trace to each method to be able to get a runtime method call in logcat.

My application crashes all the time, don't ask me to copy you the error log because that is not the point of my question.
Actually I try to inject my code just right after the register declaration: `.locals`

The first time I used the `.registers` directives but got errors because of the aliasing of local and parameters registers.

I thought then that I could use the `.locals` directive instead but it's exactly the same.

The different test that I made were the following ones:

- If the difference between the local and the parameters registers were greater than 2 I use `v0` and `v1`.
- Else I incremented the `.locals` directive by 2 and I used `v0` and `v1`.

But I keep getting VFY errors.

Why sometimes `.locals` equals 0 but there is parameters like `p0` for example. 
`p0` should be aliased by `v0` but `.locals` is 0, so why if I change this by `.locals` 2 and just use `v0` and `v1` I still get VFY?

I am thinking to add my code just before the return directive at least it will not matter if I change a local variable as long as it is not the return variable

edit:
@JesusFreke  thank you for your good comments.

I am currently trying to improve my python script with your suggestion. So I created a CustomClass that I copy in the root folder but the fact is that I loop throughout all the methods in the root folder, I get the class and method name that I store into variables then I change the value of the parameters of this function and I invoke it inside each method.

But the fact is that it cannot work because value of the parameters of the static function change each time I enter a new method and at the end it will only keep the value of the last method I entered in.

In this case I will need to generate as many static functions as I have methods in the smali folder which is around 40.000...

This is part of my code:

```
def edit_custom_class(custom_class_path, my_tag, my_message):
with open(custom_class_path, "r+") as file: 
    for line in file:
        if ('const-string p0' in line):
            file.write('\tconst-string p0, "{0}" \n' .format(my_tag))

        elif ('const-string p1' in line):
            file.write('\tconst-string p1, "{0}" \n' .format(my_message))

        else:
            file.write(line + '\n')


def process_file(file_path, custom_class_path, my_tag, file_metadata):
is_inside = False
valid_registers = []

with open(file_path, "r+") as file: 
    for line in file:
        # we get the data concerning the method and mark it as a treated method
        if (('.method' in line) and (helper.is_valid_class_or_method_directive(line)) and (is_inside == False)):
            is_inside = True
            method_data = get_method_data(helper.get_class_or_method_name(line), file_metadata)
            my_message= (method_data[0] + '->' + method_data[1])
            file.write(line + '\n')

        elif (('return' in line) and (is_inside == True) and (method_data[4] == False)):    
            edit_custom_class(custom_class_path, my_tag, my_message)
            file.write('\t# has been edited by smali-rmc-interceptor on {0} \n' .format(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())))
            file.write('\t# start editing \n')
            file.write('\tinvoke-static, {0};->e(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I \n' .format(custom_class_path))
            file.write('\t# end editing \n')
            file.write(line + '\n') 

        elif (('.end method' in line) and (is_inside == True) and (method_data[4] == False)):
            is_inside = False
            method_data = []
            file.write(line + '\n')

        else:
            file.write(line + '\n')
```

And my CustomClass content:

```
.class public LCustomClass;
.source "CustomClass.java"

.method public static add_trace()V
    .locals 0
    .parameter "tag"
    .parameter "message"

    .prologue   
    .line 10
    const-string p0, "my_tag"

    const-string p1, "my_message"

    .line 15
    invoke-static {p0, p1}, Landroid/util/Log;->d(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    .line 18
    return-void
.end method
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's easiest to avoid having to allocate new registers in an existing method. This introduces a whole slew of problems due to the register limitations of many instructions.

Your best bet is to create a separate static helper method that accepts some values and prints them out or whatever it is you're wanting to do, and then simply inject a static method call in the method that you want to instrument, without allocating any new registers.

Comment: The problem is that in fact I need two parameters because what I want to do is to print out the class name and method name of the function in which I invoke my method. So after all my test my best bet is to try to do that just before the return statement in order to avoid any kind of conflict that I encountered in all my attemps.

Comment: That won't work if there's an exception, or an early return. I would still recommend generating a static method and calling it. If needed, you could generate a static method for every method you want to instrument, and hard-code the class and method names in the static method.

Comment: That is exactly my plan for the futur version of my script. Hardcode a class file with methods in it, copy it into the root folder so I will be able to access my methods whenever I want. Nevertheless, I will still need to pass information to my methods so I will need to pass local registers. But I think I am on the good track to make my script. Any advice are welcome though. And I have a question what exactly monitor-enter does and why can't I use a register which has been use with this directive. I looked at the doc but still I don't get what does monitor-enter, monitor-exit. Thanks.

Comment: monitor-enter and monitor-exit are synchronization constructs. It would be used for things like synchronized blocks or methods in java.